# Como receber um valor decimal por QueryString no asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário que envia alguns dados, quero receber estes dados mais um deles é um valor, está vindo sem a formatação correta.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("GravarDados", "Aposta", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="container droppedHover">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" id="numero" name="numero"  placeholder="número.." maxlength="4" type="text"/>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="number"  id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="valor.."/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " type="submit" >Adicionar</button>
    </div>
}
```

```html
        public ActionResult GravarDados()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["numero"]))
            {

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["valor"])){

                    int IdDoUsuario = (int)Session["id"];
                    int numero = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["numero"]);
                    decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["valor"]);
                    var tTabela = new JogoTemAplicacao();
                    tTabela.Inseri(numero, valor, IdDoUsuario);

                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aposta");
        }
```

Comment: Por que precisa ser por `QueryString`?

Comment: Eu preciso de uma solução, independente da que seja, estou aceitando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você envia os dados da `views` para o `controller` através de método `GET` como está na pergunta, no momento de receber o resultado, eu devo receber exatamente como ele vem e não fazer uma conversão do valor:

Enviado o valor 10,20, estava sendo feito assim:

```
decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["valor"]);
```

**Resposta : 1020**

Mas se eu receber o resultado em uma `string`, eu vou ter o resultado no mesmo formado digitado:

```
string valor = Request.QueryString["valor"];
```

**Resposta : 10.20**

No momento de gravar no banco eu preciso fazer o tratamento da seguinte forma:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0:0.00}, ", VALOR_JOGO);
```

Isso resolve o problema,